# Error when installing scrapy using pypi

Tags: python, scrapy, pypi

I'm on `Debian 6` with `python 2.7` and I've tried to install `scrapy` (according to [the doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/intro/install.html)) using the command:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

and got this error

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c twisted/runner/portmap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/twisted/runner/portmap.o

twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory

twisted/runner/portmap.c:14: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

twisted/runner/portmap.c:31: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

twisted/runner/portmap.c:45: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PortmapMethods'

twisted/runner/portmap.c: In function 'initportmap':

twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Py_InitModule'

twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: error: 'PortmapMethods' undeclared (first use in this function)

twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: error: for each function it appears in.)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/Twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FSl8pj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/Twisted
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I think the problem is when installing `Twisted` library, so i tried to install it alone using:

```
pip install Twisted
```

and got the same error.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

Try installing `python2.7-dev` package.

Comment: This fixed the first `error code 1` for me, but I then ran into another that was solved by installing `python-lxml`.